# What is the web request to send a message to my telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I tried this:
https://api.telegram.org/botXXtokenxx/sendMessage?chat_id=chat_id&text=text

But this is to send a message from the bot.
But what I need to do to send to the bot? (not from the bot)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a regular Telegram client (Telegram, Telegram X, Telegram Desktop, etc) to do it manually, or if you need an API (for whatever reason)...

You need the client API.

https://core.telegram.org/#getting-started

Once you have an API key for the client API and all that, you can send messages as explained here.

https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMessage

Note that a human should be triggering this, as Telegram encourages (may be against ToS?) using a bot API for programatic access rather than the client API.